# Are there any BSD Libraries that will find the length of an mp3?

Tags: mp3, bsd

I would like any BSD libraries I would prefer python but any language is great.

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214005/is-there-a-good-non-gpl-python-libraries-for-finding-the-length-of-an-mp3

Comment: Do you mean length in bytes or length in time units (i.e. seconds)?

Comment: If you 'prefer python', why do you specify 'BSD'?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Good question guaranteed to depend on host config (could be custom or
fake descriptions) while one mentioned way is use HTTP HEAD

```
#Call HTTP HEAD in Python
import httplib
conn=httplib.HTTPConnection("www.abc.com")
conn.request("HEAD", "/dir/file1.mp3")
res=conn.getresponse()
fileSize=res.getheader('content-length')
#or res.getheaders() for all headers
conn.close()
```